# php preg match some url in javascript

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

there have some links, some are in javascript code. how to preg match there urls? (the urls could be end by `.shtml`, `.html`,  `/` or  `.jsp`, so I think regex them in single quotes, but nothing return.)

```
$sitelink = "javascript:pre('http://www.domain.com/cotagory/articles/2012/09/23/notice.shtml',%20%,500)";
//$sitelink = "javascript:box('http://www.domain.com/cotagory/articles/2012/09/23/sports/',%18%,500)";
if(strpos($sitelink,'javascript')===true){
    preg_match_all("@'(.*)'@i",$sitelink,$matches);
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the if condition to:

```
if(strpos($sitelink,'javascript') !== false){
```

The position of `'javascript'` within `$sitelink` is `0` that is not true!!!

Comment: This will always yield `true` because `strpos()` never returns `-1`

Comment: Still think matching `'javascript'` at the start of the string is better, but since OP never stated this behaviour explicitly I'll revert the DV

Answer (score 1):

The logic of matching 'javascript' at the start of the string is wrong; it should be:

```
strpos($sitelink, 'javascript') === 0
```

The regular expression could also be a little nicer:

```
preg_match("@'([^']*)'@", $sitelink, $matches);
```